# For Each is not Working for Created Element By Click

Tags: javascript, foreach

What I want : Whenever i click on any "hello" world it should alert me Hello, even on these "Hello's" they are Created By Button

Here is My code I tried `For(of)` and `ForEach()` but nothing works for me

Here is my try

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("kick");
btn.onclick = function() {
  let NewP = document.createElement("p");
  let createText = document.createTextNode("Hello");
  NewP.appendChild(createText);
  NewP.classList.add("hello");
  document.body.appendChild(NewP);
}
let allClasshello = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
let allClasshelloAr = Array.from(allClasshello);
allClasshelloAr.forEach(function popup(elemetnWithHello) {
  elemetnWithHello.onclick = function() {
    window.alert("Hello")
  }
})
```

```html
<p class="hello">Hello</p>
<button id="kick">Create ME</button>
```

**New in Javascript**

Comment: You are assigning the click handler to exactly one element, the first one. All the others are added later and thus don't have a click handler assigned to them.

Comment: So add an onclick handler to the new elements when you create them.

Comment: and i think when i Create them i should push them into the Arrey

Comment: You could do that, but that won't magically add the listener after your loop has run. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/816aekpx/

Comment: Thanks But i did this and this is working fine for me, maybe look Little bit Wired but working fine for me for now - https://codepen.io/yanjanendra/pen/bPXKWQ

Comment: It's overkill to add an event listener to each and every dynamically generated `p` element - you should use event delegation so you only need to assign one event listener and be done with it. https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` only gets called at the beginning of this code, before the user has added any elements, so the `onclick` event is only added to the first one. You need to add the `onclick` function to each newly added element:

```
btn.onclick = function(){
   let NewP = document.createElement("p");

   ...

   NewP.onclick = function(){
       window.alert("Hello")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an event handler to be set up so that you know when an element is clicked. My example uses a technique called [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) which basically means we add a single event handler to a parent DOM element - then, when the event bubbles up, we check the `event.target` to see the exact element that was clicked.

Something like below - check the comments in the code:

```js
// Vars to keep a reference to your DOM elements
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('#buttonEl');
const containerEl = document.querySelector('#containerEl');

// Event handling functions 
const pHandler = e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'P') { //This line also part of the event delegation
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
};

const buttonHandler = (e, containerEl) => {
  const pEl = document.createElement("p");
  pEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello"));
  containerEl.appendChild(pEl);
};

//Add the click handlder to the button so it will create more elements when clicked
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', e => buttonHandler(e, containerEl))

//Add a click handler to the parent container - this is called event delegation
containerEl.addEventListener('click', pHandler)
```

```html
<input id="buttonEl" type="button" value="Create HELLO" />

<div id="containerEl">
  <p class="hello">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What happened to the `<p class="hello">Hello</p>` that existed when the page loads from the OP's example?

Comment: @j08691 - Wasn't really to critical to OP understanding how to solve their issue, but I added it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the onclick event when you create the new element.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("kick");
btn.onclick = function() {
  let NewP = document.createElement("p");
  let createText = document.createTextNode("Hello");
  NewP.appendChild(createText);
  NewP.onclick = popup;
  NewP.classList.add("hello");
  document.body.appendChild(NewP);
}

function popup() {
  window.alert("Hello")
}
```

```html
<p class="hello" onclick="popup()">Hello</p>
<button id="kick">Create ME</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to distinguish between synchronous and asynchronous code.

```
let btn = document.getElementById("kick");
btn.onclick = async;
let allClasshello = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
let allClasshelloAr = Array.from(allClasshello);
allClasshelloAr.forEach(function popup(elemetnWithHello) {
  elemetnWithHello.onclick = async;
})
```

So, at the moment `forEach` is called, the `btn.onclick` handler wasn't called, reaching only `<p class="hello">` present on the DOM.

Taking your code, the moment to assing the `.hello` handler is when you create the element...

```
let btn = document.getElementById("kick");
btn.onclick = function() {
  let NewP = document.createElement("p");
  let createText = document.createTextNode("Hello");
  NewP.appendChild(createText);
  NewP.classList.add("hello"); // you dont need this if isn't used by CSS
  NewP.onclick = handleHelloClick;
  document.body.appendChild(NewP);
}
let allClasshello = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
let allClasshelloAr = Array.from(allClasshello);
allClasshelloAr.forEach(function popup(elemetnWithHello) {
  elemetnWithHello.onclick = handleHelloClick;
})
function handleHelloClick() {
  window.alert("Hello")
}
```

If you had a container for those `<p>` you can take advantage to the `addEventListener` API, subscribing to the container instead of each element...

```
let container = document.createElement("div");
container.addEventListener("click", containerClickHandler);
document.body.appendChild(container);

function containerClickHandler() {
   window.alert("Hello");
}

let btn = document.getElementById("kick");
btn.onclick = function() {
  let NewP = document.createElement("p");
  let createText = document.createTextNode("Hello");
  NewP.appendChild(createText);
  container.appendChild(NewP);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the forEach is run there is no paragraph element (NewP). To solve this problem there are two options I suggest:

- Add the onclick event listener to NewP element where you are creating it.
- Have another action that calls your below code (wrapped inside a function) on-demand to assign onclick event listener

Here are the sample working solutions:

- [Option 1 Solution - Add event listener upfront](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/web/stack/57062042-alert-option1.html)
- [Option 2 Solution - Add event listener on demand](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/web/stack/57062042-alert-option2.html)

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically created elements you'd have to attach the vent listener (in this case it's a `click` event) when you're creating them (and before appending them to the `document`).

See the next example :

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('kick'),
  alreadyInDocHello = document.querySelectorAll('.hello'); /** selecting the already in the document element to handle click event (those created dynamically will not be included here) **/
  sayHello = e => {
    e && e.preventDefault();
    alert('Hello !');
  }; /** sayHello is the function that will be called when having a click event (basically it'll show an alert saying "hello !" **/

/** add click listener for create button **/
btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let newEl = document.createElement('p'),
    createText = document.createTextNode('Hello');
  e.preventDefault();
  newEl.appendChild(createText);
  newEl.classList.add('hello');
  /** add the listener here **/
  newEl.addEventListener('click', sayHello); /** don't forget that sayHello is declared above **/
  document.body.appendChild(newEl);
});

/** click event listener for those elements that are already present in the document **/
alreadyInDocHello.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', sayHello));
```

```css
.hello {
  background: #242424;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
}

.hello:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<p class="hello">Hello</p>
<button id="kick">Create ME</button>
```

> Learn more about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function.